# Ubuntu 18.04 No audio on ALC1220

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

First I should say audio works fine on windows, so I know its not hardware, its a clean install of Ubuntu and I have the kernel version 4.15.0-29-generic. Not sure if important my motherboard is a Gigabyte Z370XP-SLI

The problem is I can get audio through my graphics card HDMI but though the rear audio panel is not working. pavucontrol shows built-in audio profile of "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output", I can change it to any of the 5.1 Output options and I get audio through my center speaker and subwoofer, however the left and right in the front and sides don't play sound, and on restart it reverts back to "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output".
Any help would be appreciated.